# Selenium webdriver java wait for element present

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to make function  wait for an element in Selenium.

```
private WebElement  waitIsClickable(By by, int n) throws Exception{

        WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,/*seconds=*/ n);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));

        return driver.findElement(by);
}
```

But when I want use it:

```
waitIsClickable(By.id("logIn"), 20).click();
```

I get an error:

> Error:(1057, 20) java: method waitIsClickable in class Functions
>   cannot be applied to given types; required: org.openqa.selenium.By,int
>   found: org.openqa.selenium.By reason: actual and formal argument lists
>   differ in length

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is the line where error is? Do you have any other calls of this method? By the error description it seems you are trying to make a call as such:

```
waitIsClickable(By.id("logIn")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your provided error stacktrace states expected two parameters while you are providing one which is `By` object. So you need check your calling reference again.*

[`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) returns either `WebElement` or throws `TimeoutException` if expected condition doesn't meet during wait, so no need to find element again. I would suggest you do some correction in `waitIsClickable` as below :-

```
private WebElement waitIsClickable(By by, long n) throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, n);
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
 }

By by = By.id("logIn");
waitIsClickable(by, 20).click();
```

Comment: The int parameter will be boxed to long. That is not the problem (look at the error message again).

Comment: @Guy oh yes you are right error states expected two param while found one. Thanks to point out..:)

Comment: @Guy But calling reference looks ok as OP provided

Comment: Assuming he/she actually posted the line witch gives the error, which I doubt.